# tf.Data: what are stragglers in parallel interleaving?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

[`interleave`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#interleave) is a `tf.Data.Dataset` method that can be used to interleave together elements from multiple datasets. [`tf.contrib.data.parallel_interleave`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/parallel_interleave) provides a parallel version of the same functionality with the help of [`apply`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#apply).

I can see that reading from many datasets in parallel and having buffers for them as allowed by the parallel version will improve throughput. But the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/parallel_interleave) also has this to say about how `parallel_interleave` can increase data throughput:

> Unlike tf.data.Dataset.interleave, it gets elements from cycle_length
>   nested datasets in parallel, which increases the throughput,
>   especially in the presence of stragglers.

What exactly are stragglers, and why does `parallel_interleave` work especially well in terms of throughput in their presence?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A straggler is a function which takes longer than normal to produce its output. This can be due to congestion on the network, or weird combination of randomness.

`interleave` does all the processing in a sequential manner, on a single thread. In the following schema, let `___` denote *waiting for IO/Computation*, `<waiting>` denote *waiting for its turn to spit an element* and `111` denote *producing the first element (`1`)*.

Suppose we have a dataset of directories `ds = [A, B, C, D]` and we produce files `1,2,3...` from each of them. Then using `r = ds.interleave(cycle_length=3, block_length=2)` will work kind of like this:

```
A: ___111___222
B:   <waiting> ___111___________222
C:   <waiting> <waiting> <waiting> ___111___222

R: ____A1____A2____B1____________B2____C1____C2
```

You see that if producing elements from B straggles, all following elements will have to wait to be processed.

`parallel_interleave` helps in two ways with stragglers. First, it starts each element in the cycle *in parallel* (hence the name). Therefore, the production schema becomes:

```
A: ___111___222
B: ___<waiting>111___________222
C: ___<waiting><waiting><waitin>111___222

R: ____A1____A2_B1____________B2_C1____C2|....|
```

Doing this helps with reducing useless waiting by waiting in parallel. The part `|....|` shows how much we saved compared to the sequential version.

The second way it helps is by allowing a `sloppy` argument. If we set it to `True`, it allows skipping over an unavailable element until it is available, at the cost of producing a non-deterministic order. Here's how:

```
A: ___111___<w>222
B: ___<w>111___________222
C: ___<w><w>111___222

R: ____A1_B1_C1_A2_C2___B2|...................|
```

Look at that saving!! But also look at the order of the elements !

---

I reproduce these in code. It is an ugly way, but it illustrates the differences a bit.

```
from time import sleep
DS = tf.data.Dataset

def repeater(val):
    def _slow_gen():
        for i in range(5):
            if i % 2:
                sleep(1)
            yield i
    return DS.from_generator(_slow_gen, tf.int8)

ds = DS.range(5)

slow_ds = ds.interleave(repeater, cycle_length=2, block_length=3)

para_ds = ds.apply(tf.contrib.data.parallel_interleave(
    repeater, cycle_length=2, block_length=3)
)

sloppy_ds = ds.apply(tf.contrib.data.parallel_interleave(
    repeater, cycle_length=2, block_length=3, sloppy=True)
)


%time apply_python_func(slow_ds, print, sess)
# 10 sec, you see it waiting each time

%time apply_python_func(para_ds, print, sess) 
#  3 sec always! you see it burping a lot after the first wait

%time apply_python_func(sloppy_ds, print, sess) 
# sometimes 3, sometimes 4 seconds
```

And here's the function to show a dataset

```
def apply_python_func(ds, func, sess):
    """Exact values from ds using sess and apply func on them"""
    it = ds.make_one_shot_iterator()
    next_value = it.get_next()
    num_examples = 0
    while True:
        try:
            value = sess.run(next_value)
            num_examples += 1
            func(value)
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            break
    print('Evaluated {} examples'.format(num_examples))
```